# painted a cell pressing button VBA EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba, button, cell, paint

I have a question and I will post a image below to better understand:

[image]

The **Button 2** will paint cells. But I want whatever cell value is in **J4**, it will be cell that going to be painted. In this case, A2 will be painted.

I want to make the **Button 2** paint a cell when clicked, but the reference of that cell is given by the value type in the **J4** cell. Whenever I change the value of cell **J4**, when I press **Button 2** will paint that value in the **J4** reference. I couldn't figure it out how to make **Button 2** recognize that the value in **J4** is actually a cell reference.

Comment: Maybe include what you have tried?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For example `ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Range("J4").Value).Interior.Color = vbYellow`

Answer (score 1):

assuming the worksheet button

- is a form control
- is called after "Button 2"
- is assigned a "Button2_Click()" macro *placed in the code pane of the sheet where it resides* (right click on the sheet name and choose "View Code" to access it)

then you can use the following code:

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Range(Range("J4").Value2).Interior.Color = vbYellow
End Sub
```

Should you need/want to assign the button a macro residing in a standard module, than you have to use a code as per @TimWilliams comment

Answer (score 0):

try this, so u can choice with inputbox and u can according to your desired color

```
Sub colourrange()
On Error Resume Next 

        Title = "Choice Cell"
        Set rngA = Application.Selection
        Set rngA = Application.InputBox("Select Range:", Title, rngA.Address, Type:=8)
    
        rngA.Interior.Color = vbRed
    
End Sub
```

*If there’s any unclear information please let me know